# Can’t figure out how to make a counter work in a if statement python

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok I have asked how to do this and I keep getting my thing closed so I had to use my second account ok here’s my code I want to be able to make the second button to appear when the clicker (my counter) is at 7 it works at 0 which is my clickers starting number

I have tried many things to make this button appear on certain things it works when I use the turtle text input but that’s not what im looking for here’s my code  I had to re write it because all my other codes are messy so I am useing the count = 0 but I changed count to clicker

This makes the button disappear but only because thats the starting number this is the code part but I included my whole code so my question doesn’t get closed

This doesn’t work and I don’t understand why when I get to 7 on the counter nothing happens

```
if clicker == 7.00:
  button = Button(window, text="cleanhouse")
  button.config(command=cleanhouse)
  button.pack()
```

This makes the button appear but only because its set at 0 I want it to appear when its at 7

```
if clicker == 0:
  button = Button(window, text="cleanhouse")
  button.config(command=cleanhouse)
  button.pack()
```

Yes there is a lot of stuff thats not necessarily to add hear but like I said I'm tired of it closing my thing so I rewrote it and tried my best to make it as simple as possible to read through it if someone could help please I have been stuck on this for ever edit im about to give up with this this is getting frustrating this is my third email I have had to sign up to ask this the last email I had to wait a hour I just wanna ask this question please let me

```
#ALL IMPORTS
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
import ttk
import sys, time
#END OF IMPORTS 

#starting the program
input = input("Do you wanna start?")

if input == "no":
  print("NEVER GONNA GIVE YOU UP NEVER GONNA LOAD SOoOooO GO AWAY!")
  quit()
if input == "yes":
  print("loading please be patient")
  for i in range(43):
    sys.stdout.write("..")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.2)
  print("loading finished!Have fun!")
elif input:
  print("you are not a good boy")
  quit()
#end of starting 

#creating the window
window = Tk()
window.title("Clicky clicker *UNPLAYABLE*")
window.geometry("500x500")
#end of window

#annoying counter thats useless 
clicker = 000
#end of counter

label = Label(window, text=clicker)
label.pack()

#creating the first button 
def begformoney():
  global clicker
  clicker += 1.00
  label.config(text=clicker)


button = Button(window, text="begformoney")
button.config(command=begformoney)
button.pack()
#end of button 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem as I don't understand it very well but here it is:

I have focused only on your GUI window so this is the modified part of the code.

```
.
.
.

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Clicky clicker *UNPLAYABLE*")
window.geometry("500x500")
#end of window

#annoying counter thats useless 
clicker = 0
#end of counter

label = Label(window, text=clicker)
label.pack()

#creating the first button 
def begformoney():
    global clicker
    clicker += 1.00
    if int(clicker) == 0 or int(clicker) == 7:
        button['text'] = 'cleanhouse'
    else:
        button['text'] = 'begformoney'
        
    
    label.config(text=clicker)


button = Button(window, text="cleanhouse")
button.config(command=begformoney)
button.pack()
#end of button 1
window.mainloop()
```

Here is a gif:

[image]

As you cas see, if you add the following if/else, it works:

```
#creating the first button 
def begformoney():
    global clicker
    clicker += 1.00
    if int(clicker) == 0 or int(clicker) == 7:
        button['text'] = 'cleanhouse'
    else:
        button['text'] = 'begformoney'
        
    
    label.config(text=clicker)
```

Comment: Thanks so much i will see if that works and let you know

Comment: You are the best it works in a way but i will make it work thanks so much for taking your time to help me i really appreciate it

Comment: It is a pleasure 